# On card click I need to call a function and send a different parameter to a function present in another component

Tags: angular, typescript

**My project details component TS file**

Requirement //I need to pass a different parameter inside activity from another component html on click i.e (click)="notifyAdmin('visited')"

Ts file:

`

```
notifyAdmin(activity){ 

     this.userData = {...this.userData,downloadActivity:activity}
1. console.log(this.userData,"userData");
    this.api.notifyDownload(this.userData).subscribe({
      next:(data:any)=>{
        console.log(this.extID,this.projectid);
        if(data.success){
          console.log("data success",data);
         
         
         
        }else{
          console.log("data failed");
          
        }
      },
      error: (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) {
          console.error("error block");
          
        }
      }
    })
    
  }
```

`

I tried using service file but the object userData has some properties which are present on that page only so I cannot do using service file

Comment: Needs better formatting

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to your problem, I will suggest the one that seems the closest to what you are looking for:

Component1.component.html (the one that has all the information of userData):

```
<button (click)="adminService.notifyAdmin(activity)">
```

Component1.component.ts:

```
class Component1 implements OnInit {
  constructor(adminService: AdminService){}
  onInit() {
    this.adminService.setUserData(this.userData);
  }
}
```

Component2.component.html:

```
<button (click)="adminService.notifyAdmin(activity)">
```

admin.service.ts:

```
class AdminService {
  private _userData;
  private _extId;
  private _projectId;

  public setNotificationData(userData, extId, projectId) {
   this._userData = userData;
   this._extId = extId;
   this._projectId = projectId;
  }

  public notifyAdmin(activity) {
   if (!this._userData || !this._extId || !this._projectId) {
     //manage this case
     return;
   }

   this.api.notifyDownload(this._userData).subscribe({
  next:(data:any)=>{
    console.log(this._extId,this._projectId);
    if(data.success){
      console.log("data success",data);
    }else{
      console.log("data failed");
    }
  },
  error: (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) {
      console.error("error block");
      
    }
  }
})
  }
}
```

The idea is that the service will be stateful, and it will store all the information needed for the notification, information that will be provided by both components. if you can't controll when each component will have the necessary information, use Observables, (hint: combineLatest will be your friend in that case).

Note: if you need to do such gymnastics it might suggest that you have a poor architecture. However it is not impossible that you would be forced to do so, maybe you are dealing with an old codebase and this is the best you can do. The solution I suggested is not optimal, in order to provide a better solution, more information about your requirements is needed